# Custom image for Compute Engine using VirtualBox

Tags: google-compute-engine

I followed the tutorial google has up on youtube for creating a custom image for compute engine using virtualbox.  (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YlcR6ZLebTM).  I chose to setup a centos 6.5 that is pretty heavily customized with the longer term goal to deploy it in some sort of cluster form.  Anyway, I build the image and got it running locally, but once I package it up and send it to the cloud, I'm finding that the image won't boot.  Here is the serial output:

```
Changing serial settings was 0/0 now 3/0
Start bios (version 1.7.2-20140912_101435-google)
Unable to unlock ram - bridge not found
Ram Size=0xc0000000 (0x0000000030000000 high)
Relocating low data from 0x000e5b80 to 0x000ef780 (size 2161)
Relocating init from 0x000e63f1 to 0xbffd3640 (size 51359)
CPU Mhz=2601
=== PCI bus & bridge init ===
PCI: pci_bios_init_bus_rec bus = 0x0
=== PCI device probing ===
Found 4 PCI devices (max PCI bus is 00)
=== PCI new allocation pass #1 ===
PCI: check devices
=== PCI new allocation pass #2 ===
PCI: map device bdf=00:03.0  bar 0, addr 0000c000, size 00000040 [io]
PCI: map device bdf=00:04.0  bar 0, addr 0000c040, size 00000040 [io]
PCI: map device bdf=00:03.0  bar 1, addr febfe000, size 00001000 [mem]
PCI: map device bdf=00:04.0  bar 1, addr febff000, size 00001000 [mem]
PCI: init bdf=00:01.0 id=8086:7110
PIIX3/PIIX4 init: elcr=00 0c
PCI: init bdf=00:01.3 id=8086:7113
Using pmtimer, ioport 0xb008, freq 3579 kHz
PCI: init bdf=00:03.0 id=1af4:1004
PCI: init bdf=00:04.0 id=1af4:1000
Found 1 cpu(s) max supported 1 cpu(s)
MP table addr=0x000fdaf0 MPC table addr=0x000fdb00 size=240
SMBIOS ptr=0x000fdad0 table=0x000fd970 size=352
Memory hotplug not enabled. [MHPE=0xffffffff]
ACPI DSDT=0xbfffe120
ACPI tables: RSDP=0x000fd940 RSDT=0xbfffe0e0
Scan for VGA option rom
Machine UUID 2abb1c26-956d-af96-7832-253f37f1f47c
WARNING - Timeout at i8042_flush:68!
All threads complete.
Found 0 serial ports
found virtio-scsi at 0:3
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@0,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@1,0
virtio-scsi vendor='Google' product='PersistentDisk' rev='1' type=0 removable=0
virtio-scsi blksize=512 sectors=20971520
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@2,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@3,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@4,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@5,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@6,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@7,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@8,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@9,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@10,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@11,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@12,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@13,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@14,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@15,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@16,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@17,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@18,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@19,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@20,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@21,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@22,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@23,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@24,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@25,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@26,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@27,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@28,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@29,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@30,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@31,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@32,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@33,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@34,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@35,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@36,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@37,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@38,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@39,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@40,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@41,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@42,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@43,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@44,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@45,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@46,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@47,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@48,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@49,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@50,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@51,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@52,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@53,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@54,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@55,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@56,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@57,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@58,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@59,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@60,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@61,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@62,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@63,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@64,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@65,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@66,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@67,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@68,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@69,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@70,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@71,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@72,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@73,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@74,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@75,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@76,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@77,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@78,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@79,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@80,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@81,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@82,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@83,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@84,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@85,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@86,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@87,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@88,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@89,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@90,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@91,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@92,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@93,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@94,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@95,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@96,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@97,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@98,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@99,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@100,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@101,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@102,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@103,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@104,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@105,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@106,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@107,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@108,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@109,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@110,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@111,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@112,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@113,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@114,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@115,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@116,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@117,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@118,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@119,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@120,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@121,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@122,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@123,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@124,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@125,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@126,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@127,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@128,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@129,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@130,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@131,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@132,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@133,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@134,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@135,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@136,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@137,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@138,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@139,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@140,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@141,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@142,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@143,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@144,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@145,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@146,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@147,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@148,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@149,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@150,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@151,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@152,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@153,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@154,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@155,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@156,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@157,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@158,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@159,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@160,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@161,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@162,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@163,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@164,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@165,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@166,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@167,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@168,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@169,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@170,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@171,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@172,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@173,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@174,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@175,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@176,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@177,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@178,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@179,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@180,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@181,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@182,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@183,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@184,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@185,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@186,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@187,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@188,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@189,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@190,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@191,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@192,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@193,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@194,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@195,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@196,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@197,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@198,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@199,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@200,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@201,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@202,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@203,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@204,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@205,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@206,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@207,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@208,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@209,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@210,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@211,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@212,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@213,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@214,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@215,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@216,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@217,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@218,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@219,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@220,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@221,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@222,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@223,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@224,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@225,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@226,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@227,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@228,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@229,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@230,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@231,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@232,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@233,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@234,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@235,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@236,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@237,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@238,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@239,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@240,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@241,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@242,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@243,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@244,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@245,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@246,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@247,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@248,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@249,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@250,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@251,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@252,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@253,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@254,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@255,0
Scan for option roms
Searching bootorder for: HALT
drive 0x000fd900: PCHS=0/0/0 translation=lba LCHS=1024/255/63 s=20971520
Space available for UMB: 000c0000-000eb800
Returned 122880 bytes of ZoneHigh
e820 map has 7 items:
  0: 0000000000000000 - 000000000009fc00 = 1 RAM
  1: 000000000009fc00 - 00000000000a0000 = 2 RESERVED
  2: 00000000000f0000 - 0000000000100000 = 2 RESERVED
  3: 0000000000100000 - 00000000bfffe000 = 1 RAM
  4: 00000000bfffe000 - 00000000c0000000 = 2 RESERVED
  5: 00000000fffbc000 - 0000000100000000 = 2 RESERVED
  6: 0000000100000000 - 0000000130000000 = 1 RAM
Unable to lock ram - bridge not found
Changing serial settings was 3/2 now 3/0
enter handle_19:
  NULL
Booting from Hard Disk...
Booting from 0000:7c00
```

Any ideas on how I can get this thing to boot?  I'd rather not customize remotely.

Input is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative, if you know what modifications you would like to make to CentOS 6.5 and can script them, you can use [Packer](https://www.packer.io/) to create custom CentOS images based on existing GCE VM images, which is much easier than building images from scratch. It will also make it easy to upgrade to new versions by re-building a new image with Packer with a new base CentOS image.

Here is more info on using Packer with GCE:

- [Google Compute builder](https://packer.io/docs/builders/googlecompute.html)

Here are some Packer example configs:

- [Ambari server/agent VM images](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-launcher/tree/master/apps/hortonworks/hdp2/ambari/packer)
- [VM images with auto-resizing disks](https://github.com/mbrukman/stackexchange-answers/tree/master/stackoverflow/24023916)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest paying close attention to the [Building an image from scratch](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images#buildingimage) docs and make sure you're following those guidelines. Since the disk isn't being found and you said that the image is "pretty highly customized", I'm wondering if you are missing kernel support, unsupported disk partitioning, or some type of disk mirroring?

Try starting with a minimal bare-bones install of a CentOS in VirtualBox and see if you can get that to work. Then you can look at making your customizations as long as you ensure the kernel has support for the virtualized environment *and* you're using a fairly simple disk partitioning scheme.